# Unable to ping my Windows Server using win_ping

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-inventory

When I tried to ping my Windows instance using `ansible windows -i hosts.ini -m win_ping`, I got the following error:

```
54.197.197.91 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
"unreachable": true
}
```

My `hosts.ini` file looks like:

```
[windows]
54.197.197.91

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=Administrator
ansible_ssh_pass=MyPassword123!
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
```

To solve that, I have done this :

```
ansible-vault create secret.yml
```

and entered my password there like this:

```
win_initial_password: MyPassword123!
```

Then, my `hosts.ini` file looked like:

```
[windows]
54.197.197.91

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=Administrator
ansible_ssh_pass={{ win_initial_password }}
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
```

When I tried pinging, I got the below error :

```
54.197.197.91 | FAILED! => {
"failed": true,
"msg": "the field 'password' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'win_initial_password' is undefined"
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: (1) you have a problem with Windows authentication and you need to resolve it; using Ansible vault has nothing to do with this mechanism and trying to do it won't change anything.

Comment: (2) Inventory file is not parsed for Jinja2 variables; it won't work this way and even if it did, it would have no effect on (1).

Comment: Do I need to change anything for getting my inventory file parsed for jinja2 variables??

Comment: Probably fork the Ansible project and write your own system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by changing these :

```
ansible_ssh_port=5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

This worked.

Comment: Could you care to explain where these lines go?

Comment: yaa raja...they have to be placed in the **hosts.ini** file as in the question

Comment: Your solution is fine if you are willing to connect with your remote nodes on unencrypted connections.  It's a little like leaving your car keys on a desk or table and hoping that nobody takes them.  Or are you planning to add encryption later?

Answer (score 5):

As I was following an Ansible example similar to the original post, the accepted answer didn't work for me, the following got it working

Note: This is sending password in plain text so don't use in production

On the target machine, run a powershell with admin rights and enter these commands:

`Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic -Value $true
 winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'`

Also verify your firewall is configured correctly to allow the necessary ports through (TCP/5985, TCP/5986)

Sources:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#authentication-options
https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/114

Comment: I googled and googled an no soltion worked until I found you answer at the end of this question!! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've googled a lot and finally the below configuration worked for me. I've added ntlm to my config file.

```
ansible_user: user@DOMAIN.COM
ansible_password: password
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_ssh_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

Still was an issue for me. My solution was to reinstall `python-pip` packages related to `winrm` from scratch. I had to use official [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html#windows-how-does-it-work). As per documentation:

1. `apt-get install python-pip git libffi-dev libssl-dev -y`
2. `pip install ansible pywinrm`
3. Port number for Windows is **5986** so you var configuration should be `ansible_ssh_port: 5986`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue even with "AllowUnencrypted" set to true. I observed that win_ping was working for `IEUser` that was added to Administrator group but failing with

```
windows-server | UNREACHABLE! => {
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
  "unreachable": true
}
```

for `test-user` that was not in Administrator group.

So I added the `test-user` to Administrator group and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

*I have installed UBUNTU18-LTE in windows and face a lot of issues. So sharing my experience with the same error. Hope this will help.*

The user must be local. **Guys remember the user(ansible) must be a local(host - 192.168.11.22) admin user** else no use of the below process.

1. Hosts file example.
   **cat /etc/ansible/hosts**
   [win]
   192.168.11.22

   [win:vars]
   ansible_connection=winrm
   ansible_user=**ansible**  # Local admin user of host machine 192.168.11.22
   ansible_password=ansible123
   ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
   ansible_winrm_transport=basic
   ansible_port=5985  #HTTP
2. Run the below command *on host PowerShell windows*.
   **winrm configsddl default**                         #Give permission to ansible user
3. Post step 2 configuration execute below 2 commands *on host PowerShell*.
   **winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'**
   **winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'**
4. The Other use-full PowerShell commands to test the winrm connection.

   1. winrm enumerate winrm/config/Listener.
   2. winrm get winrm/config
   3. WinRM quickconfig                          #Check winrm service is running
   4. winrs -r:http://hostservername:5985/wsman -u:RDPusername -p:RDPpassword ipconfig/all

Comment: Please note there is a typo in "ansible_winrm_trasport". It should be "ansible_winrm_transport"